# Variables in yaml configuration not substituted

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml, microservices, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to set up some microservices with Spring Boot and Eureka. I'm using YAML configuration and when I start up the services, they are registered with the Eureka service. The problem I have is that the environment variables in my configuration files are not substituted but are interpreted as a string (see `instanceId`).

**Example application.yml**:

```
server:
  port: 0

eureka:
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalSeconds: 10
    instanceId: ${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
  client:
    registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 5
```

**What I see on the Eureka app:**

[image]

I've Googled the problem but I can't seem to find a solution. Does anybody known why this might happen or where I could start looking for solutions? I'm fairly new to this and I don't have a clue. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if you able to use SPeL inside a `.yml` file, maybe you can, but I did notice you're missing a closing brace for the first opening brace on `instanceId`.

Comment: @jmw5598 Oh man... I'm really that stupid. Appending a } to the line fixed the problem. I'm so sorry for this stupid question. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: happens to me all the time